# Does this style of design have a name? Fun meme stuff with cats, dogs and bling-bling

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Ie. fun meme stuff with cats and dogs. Stuff you'd typically do in Photoshop in 5 minutes, with rainbow colors, Comic Sans MS etc., often combined with bling-bling and other elements from hiphop culture.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you'd probably call it meme grafix

Comment: I'd call those examples of Bad Graphic Design, and that's being polite!

Comment: I totally agree, but this style is tremendously popular among teens and young adults, and while us designers might find it deplorable, young ladies seem to think it's cute.

Comment: Its not bad, its ironic. Even if it is sincere it is ironic, in fact the more sincere this is the more ironic it gets. The internet is magic.

Comment: Collage. It's like old-school collages made with cut-outs from magazines -- (almost) all hard edges, pasted on a colored background.

Comment: All of these can be considered 'meme' images but the second one looks like some Vaporwave style

Comment: I wouldn't specifically call it [New Ugly](https://eyeondesign.aiga.org/schooled-in-the-new-ugly-lessons-from-darius-ous-autotypography/) but there are similarities...